# Wouldn't a "do until" loop be more efficient?

Tags: performance, loops, conditional-statements

I am new to programming, and one reoccuring pattern I notice is the frequent negation I have to use with `while` loops, for example `while (!isEmpty())`

Wouldn't it be better performance wise if there was a "until" loop, e.g. do something until a condition is true? I do realize negation happens on registers and is very fast, but still it looks like it can be avoided.

Or maybe there is something about assembly language that makes it preferable to use the currently established approach, even if it frequently requires negation?

Comment: I think if you're that concerned about performance (bit negation is, as you say, extremely fast) then assembler programming is the only way for you. The readability and maintability of code written in a higher level language will always be at the expense of reduced performance.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment in letter but not in spirit. You should learn some assembly programming, look at real compilers' output, benchmark (properly!) etc. to get such nonsense, misguided "optimization" thoughts out of your head. There are more problems with your assumptions and your suggested solution than I can enumerate in one comment.

Comment: @delnan - why don't you try with an answer?

Comment: Because I don't have the time to write a quality answer (as opposed to a hardly coherent list of notes) in the next few hours, and frankly, because I am fed up and frustrated with this class of misconceptions. I mean no offense, it's not your fault or anything, everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation most likely won't happen explicitly in a way that takes any time.

First off, the naive "while" implementation looks like this on x86

```
_loophead:
  call _isEmpty
  test eax, eax ; return value is in eax
  jnz _loopend  ; break out of loop if condition is not zero
  ... ; loop body here
  jmp _loophead
_loopend:
```

There is no actual negation there, just a `jnz` that "jumps if not zero". What is not zero? The last thing that affected "the flags" - the test above it that tests the return value of `isEmpty()`.

A better "while" implementation (because it takes only 1 branch per iteration) looks like

```
  jmp _looptest
_loopstart:
  ... ; loop body
_looptest:
  call _isEmpty
  test eax, eax
  jz _loopstart  ; continue loop if condition is zero
```

The negation, when it exists, takes no additional time/instructions/space. This is also the case on many other processors.

Furthermore, if `_isEmpty` can be inlined, the condition most likely *won't even really be in a register*, it'll be part of the flags state (a single bit in a special register). Things such as "a boolean is an integer that is 0 or 1" are part of the *conceptual semantics* and are often optimized out in real implementations. You usually don't need that 0/1 value - most of the time the first thing you'll do with it is put it back in the flags register again so you can branch on it.

Even very early C compilers took special effort to compile a "bool used as condition" to more efficient code than making a 0/1 integer out of it.

Comment: How can a processor check a value if it is not on the register?

Comment: @user2341104 the flags are really in a special register, as I mentioned. x86 can also kind of branch on a normal register, but only `ecx` and it's less efficient on most implementations. Some other processors use different ways of handling conditionals, such as having merged "compare/branch" instructions (such as MIPS). Still, in almost all cases you don't have to actually negate anything.