# What is a Do and While statement

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
bool setstart = true;
int main(){
  int x;
  int y;
  cout << "Welcome to the guessing game\n";
  do {
 cout << "Please enter a number from 0 to 100: ";
 cin >> x;
 } while (x < 0 || x > 100);Sleep(2000);
 system("cls");
 cout<<"ok player 2 pick the guess";
 cin>>y;
 if (x == y){
  cout<<"congrats you got it right";
       }
        else{
        if (x < y){
        cout<<"Go lower";}
        else {
        if (x > y){
        cout<<"higher";}}
        }
 system("pause>nul");
  return 0;
  }
```

I really just dont understand it. How would i use it? also does a do and while mean that Do is what is happening and while it is happening does it do the While? This is some code my friend did for me can any of you really specificly explain it?

Comment: It's not really one to be used all that much in any case.

Comment: Search for "do-while statement".

Comment: Can be looked up with trivial google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `do {} while;` loop executes exactly once before the condition is checked:

```
do {
   "//code stuff here"
} while (condition);
```

is equivalent to

```
"//code stuff here"
while (condition) {
  "//code stuff here"
}
```

Comment: Not true.  The `//stuff` in the do-while executes before `condition` gets tested the first time, which is not the case for the while.

Comment: JoeZ, look closer. ;)

Comment: Grrr... yep, I see it now.  Undoing my downvote.  It's such an unusual pattern, and a big violation of DRY that my eyes totally didn't see it the first time.

Comment: Though, if you want to be technical there should be `{}`s around the first stuff in the while loop example, to be complete with scoping and stuff.

Comment: @JoeZ you are correct I even about to down-vote first

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity what about know ?? visible red-comments :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, seems good to me. :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, fixed for grammar.

Comment: Yes, it was needed :) nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

The story behind this particular construction stems from the very begining of compilers and usage in limited CPUs.

In that time, starting your loop with a while() produced longer code thant the do/while version:

while( condition ) evaluated the condition once, then started a loop with a jump at the end:

```
if (!cond) jump to 'END' // PRE CHECK
else
'BEGIN'
do work 
if (cond) goto 'BEGIN'
'END'
```

Whereas the do{} while doesn't have this "pre-check", which saves a few instructions of assembly. In case of high-perf code, using the do{} while could mean a few percent of improvement.

Comment: nice answer, citation please?

Comment: My experience on embedded DSPs an Texas Instruments assembler? :)

Comment: that is good you answer is interesting, if you could add a reference then it would be great1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255555/wouldnt-a-do-until-loop-be-more-efficient ? http://www.easy68k.com/paulrsm/doc/trick68k.htm ? Dunno bro, you can try for yourself. Initializing the parameters smartly and have a do{} while saved me some nanoseconds on a critical IRQ handler, which amounted to a few percent speedup.

Answer (score 0):

From [Site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_do_while_loop.htm):

[image]

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   // Local variable declaration:
   int a = 10;

   // do loop execution
   do
   {
       cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
       a = a + 1;
   }while( a < 20 );

   return 0;
}
```

You need a lot of practice, then you will understand it. Do not give up, just learn. Buy a good decent book, find friends which are programmers, join IRC. Learn! It is a gate to your future.

Answer (score 0):

`while (cond) { ...body... }` and `do { ...body... } while (cond)` are nearly identical.

The only difference is that `while (cond)` tests its condition before executing `...body...` the first time, whereas `do { ...body... } while (cond)` executes `...body...` once before checking the condition the first time.

The reason you might want `do while` is that the condition you're testing is set within the loop itself, but not before.  In this case, the loop checks that `x` is in range, but `x` isn't known until the loop body executes once.